# Inserting primary key value into other column of same record in a SQL table

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, odata

I am working with a database application which adds a record to a table through a web page in Asp.Net MVC.

I have a table `Terms` with following columns'

```
Id
TermName
TermOrder
```

I am inserting a `TermName` from the webpage and I would like `TermOrder` to be same value as `Id` . 
For Example I am inserting a TermName "Fall" into the table and it adds Id by default using Identity Specification say 10 but adds 0 to TermOrder but I would like Id value that is 10 to be also in the TermOrder.

I am using knockout Js and Odata to insert a record

Knockout Js

```
self.addTerm = function (term) {
        var payload = {TermName: this.Term()};
        $.ajax({
            url: '/odata/Terms',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(payload),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json'

        });

    }
```

Controller

```
protected override Term CreateEntity(Term entity)
        {
            var newTerm = db.Terms.Find(entity.Id);
            if (newTerm == null)
            {
                newTerm = db.Terms.Add(entity);
                entity.TermOrder = entity.Id;
            }
            else
            {
                newTerm = db.Terms.Add(newTerm);
                entity.TermOrder = entity.Id;
            }

            db.SaveChanges();   

            return newTerm;
        }
```

May I know a better way to deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgI_Terms_UpdateTermOrder
ON dbo.Terms
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE  t
    SET     TermOrder = i.Id -- This will copy ID values in TermOrder
    FROM    dbo.Terms t INNER JOIN inserted i ON t.Id = I.Id
END;
GO
```

Comment: Thanks and How do I do the same but instead of inserting Id into TermOrder I would like Min(TermOrder)-1 as I cannot use aggregate function in SET